# As a Hadoop Regular User, Is There a Way to See Details about Running Jobs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I do not have access to any CLI on any of the Hadoop nodes, but I have access to the cluster via Hue and Jupyter.  The engineering team has also configured the Hadoop UI that shows New, Running, Submitted, Finish, etc. applications.  However, it appears all spark jobs have a generic name, for instance, something like this:

```
HIVE-f23fa1a1-4444-4ab2-1c44-12345a123456
```

or similar and when I click on the application_id, I get a `Failed to read the attempts of the application` error. (even for my own jobs).  Similarly, spark jobs, which you can normally name using `setAppName`, are all named generic "Spark-something" because the spark context is already initialized upon bringing up Jupyter on an edge node (i.e. I can't establish a name because one already exists).

Is there a way for a unprivileged Hadoop user to see into what job is actually running (i.e. the Hive query or the Spark / Hadoop command ), without having some sort of CLI privilege?

I have tried using a few urls that I suspect have job information in them, for instance:

`http://cluster_master:<portnum>/history/application_1234123412341234_12345/jobs/` or

`http://cluster_master:<portnum>/jobs/application_1234123412341234_12345/`

but neither attempt returns any details about the job itself (even things I named myself within the hive / spark context using `setAppName`.

Please let me know if there's a better way to ask this question. I am relatively new to Hadoop/Spark.  All the reference docs and SO answers I've found assume CLI or privileged access and I can't find any documentation in either Spark or Hadoop that applies to this problem.

Comment: Are you using YARN (Spark on YARN)?

Comment: Yes, they are using YARN and yes, we're using Spark.

Comment: Have you looked at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API?

Comment: No I hadn't.  I didn't realize I should be looking at YARN references (vs. Hadoop or Spark) but now that you mention it, I *am* asking about system resources.  Thanks.  I'll take a look and see if I can get an answer using this reference.

Comment: Did you tired of JMX for yarn it state the resource details memory vcores ? 

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EAG/Hadoop+JMX+Monitoring+and+Alerting

Comment: Hello @Proletariat, well to be able to use YARN Job manager (the ugly UI with jobs and their status) you need run your Spark job with YARN. Only then YARN will supervise your Spark jobs and therefore store their history as well